# set value of hidden input value from ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

My ajax request responds with a newtimestamp variable that I need to set on the hidden input field 'time'.

I have tried this:

```
$("#time").value(data.newtimestamp);
```

However this shows this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

html:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo "$timestamp"; ?>" name="time" id="time" />
```

Comment: It should be `val()`, not `value()`. Voting to close as off-topic due to a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery method is `val()`, not `value()`:

```
$("#time").val(data.newtimestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because `value()` is not a valid function. Try this:

```
$("#time").val(data.newtimestamp);
```