# MVC4 - @html.HiddenFor and re-bind value when insert successfully

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

let say I have a View, bind to Student Model with 2 properties: ID, Name.

ID is primary key and is set as Identity column in SQL.

Here is the situation:

1. Load Create page, ID and Name will be:

   ```
   @model Student

   @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID);
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
   ```
2. Submit form via Jquery and call API, when insert successfully, it returns ID.
3. when return $.ajax.done, I got the value of ID.
4. How could I bind this value to HiddenFor(x => x.ID) without reload the page?

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: In the callback you use a selector to alter the hidden value `$("#ID").val(id)` or `$("input[name='id']").val(id)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set value of hidden input value from ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999333/set-value-of-hidden-input-value-from-ajax)

Comment: thank Jasen va Mjwills for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID);` will help you create a hidden input with id and name are the same with your field, while value is the same with your field's value. So, if ID has value 1, it will create `<input id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="1" />`

Then, when you want to bind a new value to this input in your `jQuery`, you can just change its value

```
var ID = 2;
$('#ID').val(ID);
```

Selector `#` is used to select an element with a specific ID.

Comment: @Langthang your welcome. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: hi Mark, it worked perfect. Wish you have a nice day.

Comment: @Langthang if it works, please mark it as an answer, so that future readers would find it helpful. Thank